# C/C++: Creating simple graph library

Tags: c++

I've been thinking about creating a class in C++ on graph theory. The idea is it'll be a class to hold indefinite number of vertices and edges for a simple graph (at most one edge between a pair of vertices). The problem is how'd I store this indefinite number of vertices/edges in the most efficient way.

I came up with the idea of having dynamic pointer to array of vertices as a member in the class. However, it'd be inefficient, and I also encounter problem of how to determine the connection of vertices (I wouldn't be able to determine which vertices connect with which), if I use this method. The alternative is to create a class Vertex that suppose to contain information of its connectivity. However, because of indefinite number of edges, I cannot think of other way around other than to use dynamic variables inside Vertex. It'd make my code efficiency worse with this approach.

So is there a better approach?

Comment: humbly asking but why not use boost graph library?

Comment: I just want to create my own, so that I can tweak it as much as I like

Comment: If you're doing this as a learning exercise, then fine; but if not, Boost.Graph is already extremely extensible/tweakable, so that's no good excuse for avoiding it.

Comment: Boost Graph is one of the ugliest library I've ever seen. I've used SNAP for long time, for some reason I couldn't use SNAP. The documentation, everything is just so unnecessarily complicated and ugly, I just dropped it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not plan to frequently add and remove items from inside the collections, I'd use [STL vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). They're fast for iterating through, but not terrible for inserts and removes in the middle.

If you want to add / remove anywhere frequently, I'd use [STL lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/). They're slower for iterating, but insertion / removal is O(1).

You can then define your vertex and edge as something like:

```
class Edge;

class Vertex
{
    // ...
public:
    std::list<Edge> incomingEdges;
    std::list<Edge> outgoingEdges;
}

class Edge
{
    // ...
public:
    Vertex startpoint;
    Vertex endpoint;
}
```

Comment: but how'd I keep up with the connectivity (which vertices connect to which)?

Comment: I've added an example of how you can define them. Not sure if it's the best way, but I'd start with that.

Comment: How would the vectors work unless they were vectors of pointers?  In which case would they be faster than lists for iteration?

Comment: I don't see why they couldn't be vectors of objects as well. Also, whether it's objects or pointers, insert / remove remains a O(n) operation in a vector. That being said, I have no current opinion about whether the containers should contain objects or pointers in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You'll pretty quickly find yourself wanting both a Vertex and Edge class -- there are too many algorithms that depend on coloring, or weighting, or marking edges, and it's also simpler to mix directed and undirected edges.  The odds are good that you aren't going to really care a lot about storing the appropriate references dynamically, because that can be reduced to a vector of pointers.

Another issue to think about is if you will want to store this thing persistently.

Suggestion: try the Simplest Thing That Can Possibly Work first.  Assuming an Array class that resizes itself as needed, that will look something like

```
class Vertex {
  Array<Edge> edges ;
  VertexData vd ; // define this for the task.

  public:
     // ctor etc; quiz: what operations?
}

class Edge {
  Vertex v1, v2;
  EdgeData ed;
  public:
     // ctor etc
}
```

Construct all the vertices and edges with `new`, don't worry about performance,and write some code against these classes.

Then go back, think how you'd have *liked* to write the code, and re-implement the classes to have *that* interface.

I'm a little prejudiced, since I used to teach the book and worked for Marshall Cline and Mike Girou, but I think one of the best C++ books for someone trying to really use it effectively is [The C++ FAQBook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309831), by Cline, Girou, and Lomow.

Comment: +1, "try The-Simplest-Thing-That-Can-Possibly-Work first" is excellent advice. Great answer.